# Resistance of aluminium rectangular wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

I am working on upgrading an electromagnet design program. There are currently two types of wire used for the coil, circular and strip (read as: rectangular).

The current algorithms in this program are empirically derived with lots of undocumented constants and so one of the requirements is to move it more into the realm of accepted physics.

The formula I am using to calculate resistance is:

$$
R = \frac{\rho L}{A}
$$

These are aluminum wires so the value of $\rho$ boils down to $2.82\times10^{-8}$ at 20°C.

For circular wires this works perfectly, giving near enough the same results (enough to put it down to the increased accuracy).

For strip wires this doesn't work quite so well. The problem comes from a difference in the cross-sectional area of the wire.

The original program is doing $h^2$ as the area, where $h$ is the height of the wire. Now is that not wrong? The cross-sectional area should be $wh$ where $w$ is the width of the wire.

For example,
If the strip wire is 8.4mm by 2.8mm, the original program would do:

$$
2.8 ^ 2 = 7.84
$$

but should it not be doing:

$$
8.4\times2.8 = 23.52
$$

The entire original algorithm is:
$$
R = \frac{84.09L}{h^2}
$$

Is there a reason the original engineer may have done $h^2$ as apposed to the correct cross-sectional area?

I don't want to just declare his calculations as wrong as the results from this program have been used for the last 30 years and none of the magnets have gone bust or underperformed. Infact if anything they would have been over performing if this calculation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The difference way come from the fact the electrons repel themselves and thus tend to travel on the far edges of a conductor. In a circular section the electrons are evenly distributed around the perimeter giving you the nice predictable results.

With a rectangular section the electrons are crowding the corners changing the overall resistivity as the electron density changes around the perimeter.

PS. Consider using [FEMM](http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) to simulate electron flow through a shape.

I did a test to see the results and I got the effect I expected. The field is concentrated around the edges, and the current density around the perimeter has spikes in the corners.

[image: FEMM] [image: GRAPH]

### Update

Based on the comments I want to add that my point is that the resistivity calculation may depend on uniform current density (of sorts) and the rectangular cross section lends to non-uniform current density and thus might through the calculation off.

The overall resistance on a wire is like a weighted average of the resistance of each fiber along the wire, with the current density the weighing factors. So if for any reason (I suspect) where the current density is high, so is the resistance (a non-linear effect) then the overall resistance of the conductor is not going be summarized simply by $R=\frac{\rho}{A} L$.

Comment: Why do you say this? The charge density in a conductor is close to zero (the charge of the electrons is compensated by the charge of ions), so why should electrons repel?

Comment: Thats what electrons do. They current density is not uniform in a conductor, but concentrated at the edges. The resistivity is well defined for a uniform current density.

Comment: @akhmeteli: Think of the skin effect. The current density does not need to be uniform.

Comment: @Alexander, ja72: skin effect happens with AC, not DC.

Comment: This explanation doesn't make sense.  The electrons are always there, and are balanced by positive charges.  Current flowing only moves the electrons around, it doesn't make more of them in parts of the wire.

Comment: @ja72: I am afraid the results of your computations are not convincing. Did you take into account ion charge density? Did you consider AC or DC? I am sure you are not talking about some personal theory, so why don't you just give a reputable reference to the effect that you have in mind?

Comment: It is worth it to try to match your calculations with an numerical method program (since FEMM is free to use) and see if the resistivity mismatch is dependent on the shape. I used arbitrary conditions, with fixed DC Voltage on the conductor. As for reputable source it is called the skin effect BTW and it is used for corona calculations on high voltage transmission lines.

Comment: @ja72: So do you have a reputable reference to DC skin effect? I am afraid you may be mistaken...For example, according to http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/547639/skin-effect, "skin effect,  in electricity, the tendency of alternating high-frequency currents to crowd toward the surface of a conducting material." So Encyclopaedia Britannica does not seem to know about DC skin effect, neither do I. Again, what's your reference?

Comment: Well you got any other ideas?

Comment: @ja72: No, I don't have any profound ideas:-), but there can be all kinds of boring explanations. For example, Olin Lathrop suggested that the software was originally designed for square wires. His suggestion can be slightly modified: perhaps the wire aspect ratio was meant, for some reasons, to be constant, but not equal to unity (in the OP's example it's 1:3). However, I was not able to reproduce the OP's data - he does not even let us know all the units he uses.

Comment: Skin effect is a AC phenomenon.  It has to do with the electric field slowly penetrating into a conductor as a external voltage is applied.  This is not relevant in steady state (DC).  The entire conductor crossection gets used for DC.

Comment: The the current amplitude distribution and the EM field crowding on the corners above (which is with constant voltage, DC) is explained by what effect, if it is not skin effect?

Comment: @ja72: that's why I asked you to give a reputable reference - I just don't know what you're talking about. With all due respect, I am not sure I have to sort out the details of your computation. If you are referring to some widely recognized effect, a reference would be in order, if you use some personal theory, we are under no obligation to consider it. Again, nothing personal.

Comment: @akhmeteli: The discussion drifted a bit. What happens in the wires of the coil of the original question might be due to the skin effect. This is a pure AC phenomenon (happens with DC only in superconductors). Ja72 calculated the electric field around a homogeneous conductor which is as shown in his simulation higher at the corners than in the centers. This is a real effect but has nothing to do with the electrical conductivity. So everything is a bit mixed up in the answer and discussion but not really wrong or a personal theory either.

Comment: Yes, the discussion should be about the relationship between resistance and current density. See my updated answer for what I think is going on.

Comment: @Alexander: Well, I suspect OP considers the DC case only. If it were not so, (s)he would not have said that "For circular wires this works perfectly, giving near enough the same results" - I am sure you appreciate that skin effect takes place in circular conductors as well, not just in rectangular conductors.

Comment: @ja72: If there were "a non-linear effect", the resistance would depend on the total current through the wire. There seems to be no such dependence in the original software.

Comment: We measured the resistance of one of these magnets that use the strip wire and it turns out they are almost perfect. ~0.2Ohms difference at most. The strip wires are always 1:3 width:height ratio and the original program was based on the CGS unit system. I know the length of the wire does have an impact on the resistance, these wires can be up to 800m long (all coiled up), could this explain the difference (almost double) in resistance?

Comment: @Lerp: I am afraid I don't understand this comment: the double difference is between what and what? And what is perfect compared to what?:-)

Answer (score 1):

The original engineer may have been assuming a square crossection.  Yes, for DC anyway, the resistance of a wire is inversely proportional to the area of its corssection.

By the way, your resistivity of 2.82 x 10<sup>-8</sup> can't possibly be right, as should be obvious from a dimensional analisys alone.

Comment: I don't think he assumed a square cross-section because the height of the wires is set to a third of the height.

Why is my resistivity wrong? Every source I look at gives between $2.5$-$3\times10^{-8}$, Wikipedia says 2.82 so I used that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_of_various_materials

Comment: @Lerp: I didn't even look at the magnitude of your resistivity value, but clearly it can't be right since resistivity is not a dimensionless quantity.